# What meter and verse form does this poem have?

Tags: poetry

I found this poem a while ago, and I'm wondering what verse form and meter it utilises:

> The wrinkling sea shone dimly
>   Beneath a waxen moon.
>   The bitter gale blew bleakly
>   Against a mermaid’s croon.
>   And beneath the wistful silence,
>   As the sweaty seamen slept,
>   While sighing into the somber sky,
>   The rueful raven wept.

Comment: It's loose iambic trimeter, except for the penultimate line, which is iambic tetrameter. There should be a term for lengthening the last or second last line of a stanza or poem, as this is a pretty common technique, but I don't know it.

Comment: Yes, the 1-**2**-3 rhythm is called iambic.  The rhyme is on every second line, called A**B**C**B**

Comment: You should remove the comma from the title. It makes an unnatural separation. Say it aloud and you will see.

Answer (score -1):

Reference [Quick guide to forms](http://www.thepoetsgarret.com/quatrain.html)

This is pretty straight forward, a ballad stanza in an iambic trimeter.

[EDITED: Majority opinion is leaning toward **iambs**  -/ | -/ | -/ | - :The wrink | ling sea | shone dim | ly pause.]

There's a few extra syllables for stress but not a lot of variation.  To determine the meter, slap your thigh regularly as you recite the poem, repeat if necessary until you find an easy beat.  I talk over 3 beats per line, alternating between iambic and trochaic.  The 2nd and 4th lines rhyme, basic ballad stanza.

The wrinkling sea shone dimly

-/ | -/ | -/ | -  : iambic trimeter extra syllable

Beneath a waxen moon.

/- | /- | /- : trochaic trimeter

The bitter gale blew bleakly

-/ | -/ | -/ | -  : iambic trimeter  extra syllable

Against a mermaid’s croon.

/- | /- | /- : trochaic trimeter

And beneath the wistful silence,

-| -/ | -/ | -/ | -  : iambic trimeter  extra syllables

As the sweaty seamen slept,

-| -/ | -/ | -/ |  : iambic trimeter extra syllable

While sighing into the somber sky,

-| /- | /-- | /- | / : trochaic trimeter extra syllables plus pyrrhic substitution (/-- replaces /-)

The rueful raven wept.

-/ | -/ | -/ |   : iambic trimeter

Comment: Those are **not** trochees. You don't say *BEneath A waxEN moon.* It's iambic:  *beNEATH a WAXen MOON*.

Comment: Emphasis on BEneath and AGainst, it sounds better as trochees.

Comment: In iambic meter, you are allowed to make an occasional substitution of  a trochee, spondee, or dibrach for an iambic foot. If you read the *whole* line *BEneath A waxEN moon* in trochaic trimeter (as you have indicated in your notation), I think it sounds ridiculous.

Comment: The definition of ridiculous is "deserving or inviting derision or mockery".  Poetry is subjective and no opinion is deserving derision or mockery.

Comment: I have to agree with @PeterShor that those are not intended to be trochees; reading them as such makes the lines sound unnatural and forced, while reading them as iambs is flowing and graceful.